# Generating documentation for my own code with Haddock and stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock, haskell-stack

I have annotated my code in Haddock style and would like to generate browse-able documentation. Since I am also using stack, I want to integrate the documentation generation into the workflow. However, I have not yet been able to generate anything useful.

I can run

```
stack haddock
```

and it will generate documentation in the style I want (to be found deep inside `~/.stack/`), but it only seems to generate documentation for the packages I depend on, rather than for my own code.

When I run

```
stack haddock --help
```

I get the impression that I can use the additional argument `--haddock` to generate documentation for my own project, and `--no-haddock-deps` to leave out the documentation for my dependencies. However, when I run

```
stack haddock --haddock --no-haddock-deps
```

nothing seems to happen. If I `stack clean` first it will recompile all my code but no output is generated seeming to relate in any way to documentation.

As an intermediate solution I have also tried running Haddock by itself, i.e.

```
haddock my-source.hs
```

but then I get an error that it cannot find a module the file depends on (which is installed locally by stack). This gives me the impression that documentation generation will have to go through stack somehow. I have looked for, but not really found any explanations related to configuring my `.cabal` and `stack.yaml` files for documentation.

**TL;DR**

How can I use stack and Haddock to generate documentation for the code in my own package?

Comment: Is your project an executable or a library? I think stack only generates docs for libraries currently (for those it prints the path to the docs after the command, or you can see it from `stack path`), see here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/729 (including suggested workaround for building docs for executables with "cabal haddock").

Comment: @RüdigerHanke: Great, thanks. With that link I worked it out, indeed using `cabal haddock` and the linked suggested workaround. If you want to write it out as an answer I'll accept it, if not I can write up the solution myself. (My project is an executable.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [this ticket](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/729) on the stack issue tracker, Stack can currently only build documentation for libraries, but not executables.

Cabal can be configured to work with the stack databases with this command:

```
cabal configure --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=$(stack path --snapshot-pkg-db) --package-db=$(stack path --local-pkg-db)
```

after which you can run `cabal haddock --executables` to generate the documentation.

By the way, `stack haddock` is only a shortcut for `stack build --haddock`, so there is no need to write `stack haddock --haddock`.

Comment: I don't really understand the SO edit system yet :/ Maybe I'm going mad but I was fairly sure when I suggested the edit the `cabal configure` command was not yet in your post. Now the edit history says it was, making the edit meaningless. Anyway thanks for the answer and feel free to roll the edit back...

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden I believe for a few minutes after an answer is first posted, the author can edit it without it showing up in the history. Maybe that's what happened here.

Comment: Runing the `cabal configure ...` command returns a failure of `cabal: ghc-pkg dump failed` for me.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as @ChrisStryczynski Is there a solution for `cabal: ghc-pkg dump failed`?

Answer (score 8):

https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5ugm9s/how_to_generate_haddock_docs_for_nonlibrary_code/ddtwqzc/

The following solution only works when individual files are specified:

```
stack exec -- haddock --html src/Example.hs src/Main.hs --hyperlinked-source --odir=dist/docs
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I get warnings about primitive types such as `Int` not being available. Any way to include docs for some specific types?